# Mouse Hover in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I was wondering if someone can help me figure out the solution to a problem I am having with my script.

To give you all context, I am trying to simulate a mouse hover on a menu.  So when you put your mouse over "New Vendor", it will expand the menu with more options to choose from (in this case just "New Care Organization").  For test purposes, I want to select "New Care Organization".

**Here's the visual of the menu:**

[image]

**When I put my mouse over "New Vendor", this is what I want to happen:**

[image]

Here's what I have right now:

```
Browser("MyPage").Page("MyPage").WebElement("New Vendor").Click
Browser("MyPage").Page("MyPage").WebElement("Medical Care Organization").Click
```

For some reason, however, when I run this, "New Vendor" does not expand and therefore "New Care Organization" is not selected.  It's as if it didn't even recognize my command to expand "New Vendor" and the test fails.

I thought I was doing this right, but can anyone explain and possibly give me correct code to fix this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
If clicking  on "Medical Care Organization" opens a new page than it must Link and not WebElement. If you are using UFT, than you can spy that object.
If object spy is showing it as Link than you can simply use like:

```
Browser("MyPage").Page("MyPage").Link("Medical Care Organization").Click
```

**Option 2:**
If in normal case if you'll move your mouse manually on New Vendow and if its showing you Medical Care Organization than you use "FireEvent" "OnMouseOver".
Something like:

```
Browser("MyPage").Page("MyPage").WebElement("New Vendor").FireEvent "OnMouseOver"
```

And then you can click on "Medical Care Organization" object.

Answer (score 0):

First problem you could have is the html script on this page might have a different element name to -

```
WebElement("Medical Care Organization")
```

You could search the Html code for this element and try using the exact name in your code

Mouse hover and position is not commonly used with VBScript you could use Ghost mouse freeware applications along side your script.

Or you could use keyboard commands with VBScript to navigate and select through your web page such as Tab and enter.